# Javascript: how to interrupt caller chain? [answer]

Tags: javascript, html, dom, serialization

I was looking for answer to this question some time ago and I must say that most of aswers were "use strict". However I didn't want to use strict. And while ago I found out that it is possible to break chain without strict and it's quite simple:

```
function mySecretFunc(untrustedCallback, uberImportantArgument){
  [null].map(function(){untrustedCallback()});
}

//async way:
function mySecretFunc(untrustedCallback, uberImportantArgument){
  window.setTimeout(function(){function(){untrustedCallback()}},0);
}
```

note: Events fired by .dispatchEvent do NOT break caller chain
note2: remember that property getters can also intrude caller chain, this method can be also used to remove getters from array (`array.map(function(a){return a})`)

I just think it may be usefull.

Comment: Thanks for the information but what you might want to do instead is ask the question is if you were googling for it then choose the "Answer your own question" option to include the solution. It's a lot more useful for other people.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand either the question or the answer.  What was the problem in the first place?